# Why can't I add Integer to Double in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Why is it that I can do:

```
1 + 2.0
```

but when I try:

```
let a = 1
let b = 2.0
a + b

<interactive>:1:5:
    Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type `Double'
    In the second argument of `(+)', namely `b'
    In the expression: a + b
    In an equation for `it': it = a + b
```

This seems just plain weird! Does it ever trip you up?

P.S.: I know that "1" and "2.0" are polymorphic constants. That is not what worries me. What worries me is why haskell does *one* thing in the first case, but *another* in the second!

Comment: As the meme goes, "needs more `fromIntegral`".

Comment: Kind of reminds me of `x.f()` vs `g=x.f; g();` in Javascript. It sucks when variables break the substitution model abstraction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use GHCI to learn a little more about this. Use the command `:t` to get the type of an expression.

```
Prelude> :t 1
1 :: Num a => a
```

So `1` is a constant which can be any numeric type (`Double`, `Integer`, etc.)

```
Prelude> let a = 1
Prelude> :t a
a :: Integer
```

So in this case, Haskell inferred the concrete type for `a` is `Integer`. Similarly, if you write `let b = 2.0` then Haskell infers the type `Double`. Using `let` made Haskell infer a more specific type than (perhaps) was necessary, and that leads to your problem. (Someone with more experience than me can perhaps comment as to why this is the case.) Since `(+)` has type `Num a => a -> a -> a`, the two arguments need to have the same type.

You can fix this with the `fromIntegral` function:

```
Prelude> :t fromIntegral
fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b
```

This function converts integer types to other numeric types. For example:

```
Prelude> let a = 1
Prelude> let b = 2.0
Prelude> (fromIntegral a) + b
3.0
```

Comment: The [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) is the reason why `let` causes a specific type to be chosen. You can override this by giving it a type signature, or by doing `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` in GHCi (or the equivalent flag when compiling).

Comment: Is there need to set the flag when compliling? I thought that compiler does not do "defaulting"...

Comment: @drozzy: It does. GHCi just has slightly different defaulting rules. Most notably, GHCi allows a larger set of class constraints to be defaulted, and it adds `()` to the list of default types.

Comment: The key issue isn't really the different defaulting rules though, but rather that when compiling a file GHC only apply defaulting to satisfy the monomorphism restriction after analysing the **whole** file. But when you type statements into GHCI, it has to fully evaluate each statement as it's entered. So the monomorphism restriction is much less irksome when compiling whole files, as the defaulting will take into account the manner in which you use the variable. In GHCI you're typically typing statements like `let x = 3`, and a (monomorphic) type has to be chosen for `x` with no context.

Answer (score 20):

The type signature of `(+)` is defined as `Num a => a -> a -> a`, which means that it works on any member of the `Num` typeclass, but both arguments must be of the same type.

The problem here is with GHCI and the order it establishes types, not Haskell itself. If you were to put either of your examples in a file (using `do` for the `let` expressions) it would compile and run fine, because GHC would use the whole function as the context to determine the types of the literals `1` and `2.0`.

All that's happening in the first case is GHCI is guessing the types of the numbers you're entering. The most precise is a `Double`, so it just assumes the other one was supposed to be a `Double` and executes the computation. However, when you use the `let` expression, it only has one number to work off of, so it decides `1` is an `Integer` and `2.0` is a `Double`.

EDIT: GHCI isn't really "guessing", it's using very specific type defaulting rules that are defined in the Haskell Report. You can read a little more about that [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html).

Comment: First off, I upvoted. But as I have a habit of nitpicking: A static type system can support adding numbers of different types just fine. It's just that the definition Haskell settled for (`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`) doesn't allow it. (It doesn't play too well with type inference though, which is likely the reason it wasn't done.) Also, your answer may be clearer if you explictly ("guess" doesn't do it justice IMHO) explain type defaulting and the fact that literals are polymorphic.

Comment: "Haskell has a static type system, so you'll never be able to add two different types together." That's a bit of oversimplification. A lot of languages have static type systems and allow adding ints to doubles. The keyword here is that Haskell has no implicit conversions.

Comment: Yeah I didn't feel like I had a good enough handle on type defaulting and such to explain it. Feel free to add your own answer with that stuff.

Comment: You have the right of it - but you are not answering the question posed. Can you add - as the first line of your answer, the following: "The problem is with "ghci" interpreter. If you were to write the same (taking out the "let" of course) in a file, and then compile it - it would work out ok." And then leave the rest of your answer, I will accept.

Comment: Edited. This is sort of a messy answer and both other answers have useful stuff I didn't really mention, so make sure you look at those too.

Comment: @drozzy: That's not entirely correct. The monomorphism restriction is also applied in the compiler. The difference is that when compiling, all definitions are type checked in one go, so it would default `a` to `Double`, because of the way you used it. However, if you try to use `a` once in an `Integer` context and once in a `Double` context, you'll get the same problem because without a type signature the compiler will still try to infer a monomorphic type for `a`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of script-file that would have the same problem then?

Comment: If you wrote something in a file like: `a = 1; b = 2.0; useless = div a 3; add = a + b` it won't compile, because you've used a in an `Integer` context (with `div`) and a `Double` context with `add`.

Answer (score 12):

The first works because numeric *literals* are polymorphic (they are interpreted as `fromInteger literal` resp. `fromRational literal`), so in `1 + 2.0`, you really have `fromInteger 1 + fromRational 2`, in the absence of other constraints, the result type defaults to `Double`.

The second does *not* work because of the monomorphism restriction. If you bind something without a type signature and with a simple pattern binding (`name = expresion`), that entity gets assigned a monomorphic type. For the literal `1`, we have a `Num` constraint, therefore, according to the [defaulting rules](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4), its type is defaulted to `Integer` in the binding `let a = 1`. Similarly, the fractional literal's type is defaulted to `Double`.

It will work, by the way, if you `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` in ghci.

The reason for the monomorphism restriction is to prevent loss of sharing, if you see a value that looks like a constant, you don't expect it to be calculated more than once, but if it had a polymorphic type, it would be recomputed everytime it is used.

Answer (score 3):

Others have addressed many aspects of this question quite well. I'd like to say a word about the rationale behind why `+` has the type signature `Num a => a -> a -> a`.

Firstly, the `Num` typeclass has no way to convert one artbitrary instance of `Num` into another. Suppose I have a data type for imaginary numbers; they are still numbers, but you really can't properly convert them into just an `Int`.

Secondly, which type signature would you prefer?

```
(+) :: (Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> a
(+) :: (Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> b
(+) :: (Num a, Num b, Num c) => a -> b -> c
```

After considering the other options, you realize that `a -> a -> a` is the simplest choice. Polymorphic results (as in the third suggestion above) are cool, but can sometimes be too generic to be used conveniently.

Thirdly, Haskell is not [Blub](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html). Most, though arguably not all, design decisions about Haskell do not take into account the conventions and expectations of popular languages. I frequently enjoy saying that the first step to learning Haskell is to unlearn everything you think you know about programming first. I'm sure most, if not all, experienced Haskellers have been tripped up by the Num typeclass, and various other curiosities of Haskell, because most have learned a more "mainstream" language first. But be patient, you will eventually reach Haskell nirvana. :)